# All CPU meter: replacement on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cpu, gpu, cpu-usage

Way way way back before windows 10 was even a thing. There used to be a thing called all CPU meter and one for GPU as well.

They are great when you have dual monitor and want to know if CPU usage spiked a lot or what not while playing a game on the main monitor. It doesn't even hurt that you can see if a video game froze and crash on top of other usages.

However with windows 10 64 bit (gaming reason) being the main OS to be on now. Gadget cease to be a thing long ago because of security concerns which is understandable. However it does leave me without an alternative option that I am current aware of. I want it to be easy to move around across multiple-monitor so something like sidebar system resource monitor wouldn't be that good. Ditto for that tiny task manager icon on the taskbar. Especially since the taskbar are usually obscured by the game in fullscreen already anyway.

Heck at this point I would settle for something little less feature.
For reference:
http://addgadgets.com/all_cpu_meter/
http://win7gadgets.com/pc-system/gpu_meter_24.html

Comment: Why not just put Task Manager on your second screen with it open on the Performance tab?

Comment: For one thing take up lot of space compared to all cpu meter. Another is it show GPU cycle/ram usage where task manage shows NOTHING at all with respect to GPU. Furthermore you can see CPU and ram nuancy detail both at once with all cpu meter. You have to alt+tab to change between either CPU or RAM detail view but not both. The "final nail in task manager coffin" is that it will only show total CPU-wise usage not per cores. Sure you can change to process tab to see CPU/RAM but still doesn't show you the detail at all just an overall view.

Comment: I completely forgotten one more critical thing. It also show temperature of both CPU/GPU. Basically task manager is build to fit a wide audience but not necessary a good replacement to the all cpu/gpu meter.    Bottom line I rather have more info on my hand on as opposite to relying on an "inferior" version.

Comment: install the sidebar again in win10 and run your gadget again. I also do this in Windows 10.